# android intellij add directory with class files

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to include a library into my android project using IntelliJ IDEA v10.0.3. The .jar library is, however, corrupt, so I want to include the **bin** directory into the project.

What I am doing: I go to **File - Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies - Add - Library - New Library**. In the dialog that appears, I give the library a name, then click **Attach Classes...**, then choose the **bin** directory. I then click ok.

The library appears to be working fine. I get code completion and use the classes as desired. However, when I run the project, I get the following error:

**Error! C:[Path-to-library-project]\bin is a directory. Directory libraries are not supported**

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a valid jar from the required classes and use standard jar library. It's Android specific limitation.